# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'-python

Tags: python, string, dataset, data-science, attributeerror

```
for dataset in titanic:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset.Name.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
pd.crosstab(titanic['Title'], titanic['Sex'])
for dataset in titanic:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace([
        'Lady', 'Countess', 'Capt', 'Col','Don', 'Major',
        'Rev', 'Sir', 'Jonkheer', 'Dona', 'Dr'], 'Rare')
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace(['Mlle', 'Ms'], 'Miss')
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace('Mme', 'Mrs')
titanic[['Title', 'Survived']].groupby(['Title'], as_index=False).mean()
```

I got this error and can't see the mistake. I want to create a new feature based on the title in the name and divide it into categories.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0537f25296b4> in <module>()
      1 for dataset in titanic:
----> 2     dataset['Title'] = dataset.name.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
      3 pd.crosstab(titanic['Title'], titanic['Sex'])
      4 for dataset in titanic:
      5     dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace([

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Can you show us the `titanic` dataframe?

Comment: I guess "titanic" is the `dataframe` itself, so doing `for` on it just gives you one column name of it at a time. Drop the loop.

Comment: Your code says "Name" (upper case) but the error says "name" (lower case). I think you've somehow changed to an incorrect lower case name and should go back to the original.

Comment: What type is `dataset`? Is it a pandas dataframe. That's important information. Dataframe columns can be address by index `dataset["Title"]` or attribute `dataset.Title`, as long as the column name fits python's attribute naming rules. It can be less confusing to stick with one naming convention or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the issue is you are iterating through the dataframe and its impossible to find `dataset['Title']` and `dataset.Name` at the same time (Iteration). This iteration only capable of getting column names. Instead of `dataset.Name` use titanic data frame to get the column by using `titanic['Name']`